# How to solve an error while sending a get request in chatbot using ibm watson?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

when I send a get request on postman session id is not generated instead it goes on catch block and shows an error occured, please help me solve this problem

```
const authenticator = new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: process.env.WA_ASSISTANT_APIKEY,
});

const assistant = new AssistantV2({
    version: "2019-02-28",
    authenticator: authenticator,
    url: process.env.WA_ASSISTANT_APIKEY,
});

router.get("/session", async (req, res) => {
    //if successfull
    try{
        const session = await assistant.createSession({
            assistantId: process.env.WA_ASSISTANT_ID,
        });
        res.json(session["result"]);
    //error
    }catch(err){
        res.send("An Error occured while processiong your request!");
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL6RH.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Njk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that your app is trying to connect to Watson Assistant on localhost. I suspect the error is due to your line -

```js
url: process.env.WA_ASSISTANT_APIKEY
```

`APIKey` is very unlikely to be a url.